# Criar um array com variáveis dinâmicas

Tags: php, array

Precisei criar variáveis dinâmicas e utilizei este script:

```
for($i=1;$i<=40;$i++){
   ${"horario" . $i} = get_custom_field('horario'.$i);
}
```

Ela me gera as variáveis $horario1, $horario2, ...

Agora preciso agrupar todas essas variáveis em um array. Como faço isto?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acho que essa seria uma solução.

```
for($i=1;$i<=40;$i++){
   $myArray[${"horario" . $i}] = get_custom_field('horario'.$i);
}
```

Nesse caso a variável $myArray teria a lista de todas as variáveis e seu valor.